# Symfony 4.3 Route Collision in API

Tags: api, symfony, symfony4

```
* @Route("/vehicle/{id}", methods={"GET"})

* @Route("/vehicle/categories/", methods={"GET"})
```

When I try to reach my API vehicleCategories without passing any parameters, symfony takes the first vehicle API and interprets "categories" as a parameter. How can I avoid this behaviour?
Both APIs are in the same controller.

Comment: Routes are loaded by their order, so move the code of the second method before the first (inside the controller) and clear the cache before try.

Comment: Yes, already figured that out but is this really the "correct" solution? I'm afraid that someone could rearange the code at some point, what will break everything...

Comment: If your code can be modified by someone who doesn't know how Symfony works, I think this won't be the only problem you may have in the future;) PS: anyway if you introduce functional tests you can reduce the risk that this happen

Comment: Cant you add any kind of requirement to the "id"? E.g. it should always be an integer. If your routes overlapp, you need to create better definitions.

Comment: I would use a different name for the other route because it is too close to the one with the param.

Answer (score 1):

If your "id" is always an integer, you can add a requirement in your route to avoid collision

```
 @Route("/vehicle/{id<\d+>}", methods={"GET"})
```

EDIT :

Or as said in the comments with a different and more comprehensive syntax

```
@Route("/vehicle/{id}", methods={"GET"}, requirements={"id": "\d+"})
```

Comment: Note than you can also use  @Route("/vehicle/{id}", methods={"GET"}, requirements={"id": "\d+"}) if you prefer the syntax

Comment: That's true @MaximeEychenne, and that is more comprehensive, I will edit my answer, thanks !